# How to correctly save the values of a multidimensional array into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The next code creates a random multidimensional array, named 'arista', and fills each of the slots of the md-array with integers.

Then, it prints it. And you can see how are the slots filled with integers. 
Then I tried to create an array, called 'lista', which should be a list containing ALL the values stored in the multidimensional array, by typing:

```
System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(lista));
```

But the result is not what I expected. Only the last row of 'arista' appears in the array 'lista' and the other portion of the slots of the array 'lista' are zeroes.

How could I correct this? what is wrong?

The complete code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int renglones = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;
    int columnas = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;

    int[][] arista = new int[renglones][columnas];

    int[] lista;
    lista = new int[renglones * columnas];
    int k = 1;  

    for (int i=0; i < renglones; i++ ){
        for (int j=0; j < columnas; j++) {

        arista[i][j] = k++;
        lista[j] = arista[i][j];

        }

    }

        for (int i = 0; i < renglones; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            System.out.printf("[%d][%d] = %d \n", i, j, arista[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

        System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(lista)); 


}
```

Comment: use a debugger and go through it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Your re-use of `j` as the index for `lista` is incorrect.  Think about how that index should change as both `j` _and_ `i` change.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Aominè While I agree the OP needs to spend some time in a debugger, the question being asked has nothing to do with debuggers, and thus the duplicate vote is inappropriate.  Other close vote reasons are available and more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @rgettman I thought I should change to `lista[i*j] = arista[i][j];` but that doesn't work very well either

Comment: @JoeC I am learning how to debug, and probably will go through it. My example is a minimal, an verifiable example, though. The specific line of codes in which I have doubts are, are `System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(lista)); ` and  `lista[i*j] = arista[i][j];` I dont care about the downvotes BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your re-use of `j` as the index for `lista` is incorrect.  When `j` starts over at `0`, it will overwrite the contents of the first `j` entries, leaving only the last row at the end.

Multiplying `i` by `j` won't work either; when either of them are `0`, then you will overwrite the first entry, because your calculated index will be `0`.

When `i` goes from `0` to `1`, you want to start at an index number past the first `columnas` entries, not `0`.  When `i` goes from `1` to `2`, you want start at index `2*columnas`.

```
    -- 1st row --               -- 2nd row --
[0][1]...[columnas - 1] [columnas][columnas + 1] ... [2*columnas - 1] ...
```

Multiply `i` by `columnas` then add `j` to get your index.

```
lista[i*columnas + j] = arista[i][j];
```